# Boot problem in dual-boot iMac

Tags: boot, grub2, mac, refit

I know there are too many booting problem posts in geek forums, but none of them could help me so i decided to ask here.

I have been using my iMac with Ubuntu 10.04 for almost 1 year. It was perfect and i had no problem, until i decided to make a triple-boot with windows7.

I have repartitioned my drive and and tried to install windows7. It failed. But it also damaged my system. Now i am not able to boot ubuntu. For 3 days i have been trying all the things that are written on the forums, but i really couldn't solve the problem.

First, i got a frozen tux logo when i try to boot ubuntu from refit. Then i boot with gparted and deleted the ntfs partition, reformatted it to ext3 and merging it to my ubuntu partition (sda4) i hoped getting everything same as 3 days before could solve the problem. But it couldn't. now i have a gray windows like icon on refit instead of tux logo and it says boot legacy os from hd. if i try to boot it, it frozen like tux logo, but when i try to boot from apple boot thing (with holding option key) it says "missing operating system, no bootable device blabla"

I have tried synchronize the tables, didnt work.
I have also tried restoring mbr and reinstalling grub with boot-repair-disk with every combo of options, (reinstalled grub on sda and sda4, tried to restore mbr on efi, mac and linux parts) they really don't work.

I also boot with live ubuntu cd, and tried to setup grub from terminal. but i failed again.

Please show me another way to fix this. or at least tell me what is the reason that i can't boot ubuntu. (i can boot macos)

I have backed up my personal files with live cd, i will just reinstall ubuntu if i can't fix this, but i'm afraid of ending up with the same result.

Sorry for the long post, i thought giving the details can help you guys determine the problem. 
thanks.

Comment: As this question is old can you add some updated information ie:have you re-installed ubuntu and solved your problem?

Comment: added an update :-)

Comment: Can you convert your update to an answer and accept it as a solution, as part of the site clean up we are trying to get as many unanswered questions solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did use [boot-repair-disk](http://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair-cd/home/Home/) and it helped alot. If you have any booting problem you can check it.